# ANSI/ISO plans for LIMIT standardization?

Tags: limits, sql-standard

Are there currently plans to standardize one best way of limiting the number of results returned by a query?

The stack overflow question at [Is there an ANSI SQL alternative to the MYSQL LIMIT keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123) lists the various ways to handle this behavior in different languages:

```
DB2 -- select * from table fetch first 10 rows only 
Informix -- select first 10 * from table 
Microsoft SQL Server and Access -- select top 10 * from table 
MySQL and PostgreSQL -- select * from table limit 10 
Oracle -- select * from (select * from table) where rownum <= 10
```

I don't play in DBs that often so I'm speaking from ignorance here, but it seems like this is a pretty important functionality - at least important enough that I scratch my head when I see it has been left up to vendors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The latest draft SQL standard that I could find on the internet (dated 21/12/2011) has the following available for use in a query expression:

```
<result offset clause> ::=
    OFFSET <offset row count> { ROW | ROWS }

<fetch first clause> ::=
    FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ <fetch first quantity> ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }
```

Comment: This is also what the Postgres manual claims: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT